# How to get the content of an XML node (or transform a PowerShell function into C#)

Tags: c#, xml, powershell, odata

I am trying to get the content of an xml node using c# to create a PowerShell binary module. The cmdlet takes in an XmlElement array and then is able to get the first level of node, but I can't seem to find a way to get the second level of the node. Here's what I have right now.

This is the input parameter:

```
public XmlElement[] Records;
```

Here is what I've gotten so far with the body:

```
XmlNodeList temp = Records[0].GetElementsByTagName("content");
var test = temp.Item(0).Attributes;
```

But it doesn't seem to have any attributes and I don't know how to cast the nodelist back to an element to do another getelementsbytagname call. Basically I'm trying to turn this line from the function below with the above code and can't make any progress, specifically on the .content.properties call because I have no idea how to do something similar in C#:

```
($Records | Select -First 1).content.properties
```

If it's any help here is the PowerShell function I'm trying to transform into C#:

```
Function Invoke-Transform {
    #[OutputType([System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject])]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)] $Records
    )
    Begin{
        $PropertyNames = $null
        [int]$TimeOffset = if((Get-Date).IsDaylightSavingTime()){1} else{0}
    }
    Process{
        if(!$PropertyNames){
            $Properties = ($Records | Select -First 1).content.properties
            if($Properties){
                $PropertyNames = $Properties | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select -ExpandProperty name
            }
            else{
                $PropertyNames = 'NA' -as [System.String]
            }
        }
        if($PropertyNames -is [System.String]){
            $Records | Select -ExpandProperty value
        }
        else{
            ForEach($Record in $Records){
                $h = @{'ID' = $Record.ID}
                $Properties = $Record.content.properties

                ForEach($PropertyName in $PropertyNames){
                    $TargetProperty = $Properties.$PropertyName
                    if($TargetProperty -is [System.Xml.XmlElement]){
                        try{
                            $h.$PropertyName = $TargetProperty.'#text'
                            ## see if we need to adjust for daylight savings
                            if($TimeOffset -and ![System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($h.$PropertyName) -and ($TargetProperty.type -match 'DateTime')){
                                $h.$PropertyName = (Get-Date -Date $h.$PropertyName).AddHours($TimeOffset)
                            }
                        }
                        catch{}
                    }
                    else{
                        $h.$PropertyName = $TargetProperty
                    }
                }

                [PSCustomObject]$h
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong and should be using another method to try and get the children properties.

Here is a sample of the XML element that would be at the input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<feed xml:base="http:// **BLOCKEDFORPRIVACY**/OData/v3/Data/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"> 
  <id>http:// **BLOCKEDFORPRIVACY**/Odata/v3/Data/Sessions</id> 
  <title type="text">Sessions</title> 
  <updated>2020-08-19T16:20:12Z</updated> 
  <link rel="self" title="Sessions" href="Sessions" /> 
  <entry> 
    <id>http:// **BLOCKEDFORPRIVACY**/OData/v3/Data/Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')</id> 
    <category term="**BLOCKEDFORPRIVACY**" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /> 
    <link rel="edit" title="Session" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ApplicationErrors" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="ApplicationErrors" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/ApplicationErrors" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ApplicationFaults" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="ApplicationFaults" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/ApplicationFaults" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ApplicationInstances" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="ApplicationInstances" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/ApplicationInstances" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ConnectionFailureLogs" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="ConnectionFailureLogs" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/ConnectionFailureLogs" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Connections" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Connections" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/Connections" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CurrentConnection" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CurrentConnection" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/CurrentConnection" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Failure" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Failure" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/Failure" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/LogOnMetrics" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="LogOnMetrics" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/LogOnMetrics" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Machine" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Machine" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/Machine" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ProbeLogs" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="ProbeLogs" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/ProbeLogs" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ProbeLogsDesktop" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="ProbeLogsDesktop" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/ProbeLogsDesktop" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Processes" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Processes" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/Processes" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/SessionAutoReconnects" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="SessionAutoReconnects" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/SessionAutoReconnects" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/SessionMetrics" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="SessionMetrics" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/SessionMetrics" /> 
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/User" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="User" href="Sessions(guid'd0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7')/User" /> 
    <title /> 
    <updated>2020-08-19T16:20:12Z</updated> 
    <author> 
      <name /> 
    </author> 
    <content type="application/xml"> 
      <m:properties> 
        <d:SessionKey m:type="Edm.Guid">d0e6d7d7-0f83-4db0-8f7e-6c2f1b18c6c7</d:SessionKey> 
        <d:StartDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-07-10T14:33:19.947</d:StartDate> 
        <d:LogOnDuration m:type="Edm.Int32">27694</d:LogOnDuration> 
        <d:EndDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-07-10T14:43:26.837</d:EndDate> 
        <d:ExitCode m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ExitCode> 
        <d:FailureDate m:type="Edm.DateTime" m:null="true" /> 
        <d:ConnectionState m:type="Edm.Int32">3</d:ConnectionState> 
        <d:SessionIdleTime m:type="Edm.DateTime" m:null="true" /> 
        <d:ConnectionStateChangeDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-07-10T14:43:26.837</d:ConnectionStateChangeDate> 
        <d:LifecycleState m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:LifecycleState> 
        <d:CurrentConnectionId m:type="Edm.Int64">20022</d:CurrentConnectionId> 
        <d:UserId m:type="Edm.Int64">2</d:UserId> 
        <d:MachineId m:type="Edm.Guid">fca98d0d-19e4-467f-8158-6866dcf32990</d:MachineId> 
        <d:SessionType m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:SessionType> 
        <d:IsAnonymous m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsAnonymous> 
        <d:CreatedDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-07-10T14:33:42.287</d:CreatedDate> 
        <d:ModifiedDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-07-10T14:43:26.837</d:ModifiedDate> 
      </m:properties> 
    </content> 
  </entry> 
</feed>
```

Basically I want to access the property names and values in the bottom section after the `<m:properties>` tag

The Image shows a sample output of the Invoke-Transform function when run in PowerShell. I'm hoping to achieve a similar result with C#.
[Invoke-Transform Output Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8meem.png)

And update of what I have in my C# class so far. It just gives a null output so I'm not sure if I'm formatting the Element name wrong or what but if I get the element **content** then it should have a bunch of fields of properties as listed in bottom section of the XML doc.

```
    [Cmdlet(VerbsLifecycle.Invoke, "Transform")]
    public class InvokeODataTransform : PSCmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
        public XmlElement[] Records;

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            base.ProcessRecord();
            if (PropertyNames == null){
                var temp = Records[0].OuterXml;
                XElement tempo = XElement.Parse(temp);
                var tempor = tempo.Element("content");
                WriteObject(tempor);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does the individual xml elements in `Records` come from? And what does your XML document look like?

Comment: Your Powershell code is actually using C# (or rather, .NET calls) in a very inefficient way. You can query an XML document using XPath or LINQ to XML and get the elements you want directly. There's no reason to iterate over all of them. Your code looks like an attempt to deserialize an XML document into a Record object, something that's already available in .NET too, through the XmlSerializer class. What are you trying to do? What does the XML document and the Record object look like?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the xml elements come from an API call to an OData rest API

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm basically trying to turn an xml object into a custom object with the data fields so that I can manipulate the individual data fields in other classes. The XML document comes from an API call to an OData rest API, I can provide a sample of the XML document if that would be helpful? I'm very new to coding in C# so any guidance you could provide me on how to transform this function in to C# would be super appreciated.

Comment: Please post a sample XML document

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I added a sample Xml doc to the original post

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added a sample Xml doc to the original post

Comment: Right - I strongly suspect the problem is that you're asking for an XML element that's in a namespace, but you're not specifying the namespace. LINQ to XML makes this much easier than the XmlDocument API you're currently using.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tested using the LINQ to XML with an XDocument but I still didn't have any luck with getting the fields that I wanted. It's probably because despite my research I'm still no 100% sure how to use all the methods. If you had any guidance on how to use either the linq methods or the standard methods it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Currently I'm finding it hard to understand the question, due to not understanding PowerShell. If your question is really "how do I get at a specific element/attribute in a document" then reducing it to *just* that, with a [mcve] of what you've tried and what happened, would make it easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet Basically I want it an object that has the property name and property value as the PowerShell outputs in the image. I've updated the post with an example of what I've tried in C# to get the specific elements.

Comment: @user14132058 please *forget about PowerShell* - you aren't even using it, you're using *.NET* calls to deserialize XML. Posting an attempt to use PowerShell from C# only to end up calling C# classes again doesn't help anyone. What you posted is an *OData feed*, for which C# (and by extension PowerShell) already supports. You didn't need to write any of the original code. You could create an OData client directly from Visual Studio or the command line to query the OData service directly and get back strongly-typed objects

Comment: @user14132058 the Visual Studio docs [explain how to create an OData client for a specific service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/code-generation-tool) and use it to send queries and get results

Comment: @user14132058 OData can return results in XML or (preferably) JSON. You could replace all this Powershell code with a simple [Invoke-RestMethod call](https://audministrator.wordpress.com/2015/01/03/getting-odata-using-powershell/) that would return the results as already parsed objects. In C#, you can do the same if you request the results in JSON format when you make the HTTP request and deserialize the JSON string eg with JSON.NET, either to a strongly typed entity, `dynamic` or just use the JObject result as a dictionary

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for the suggestions, I will give them a try. As I mentioned in the post, I am very new to C# so any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use in c# xml linq and a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement properties = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "properties").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace mNs = properties.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("m");
            XNamespace dNs = properties.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("d");

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = properties.Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The XML sample is an OData response. The OP shouldn't have to manually deserialize it, the OData client should do that

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : Why make code more complicated than necessary?  The Op doesn't need to create a OData.  Op is just asking how to get the data in c# and doesn't care the method used.

Comment: Precisely - and trying to parse the XML won't produce the entity. The OP would have to learn the schema of the OData response, the schema of all entities, read which one is used from the `feed/id` element, create that entity manually and fill it from the `feed//entry/content/properties` elements. What could be a single line ends up being a *lot* of lines that require intimate knowledge of both OData and the specific schema used by the target service

Comment: My code works and is simple with only a few lines of code.